# Are 3rd-party controls and MVC anathema?

Tags: mvc, third-party-libraries, 3rd-party

At http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/552846/Why-s-How-s-of-Asp-Net-MVC-Part-1, I read this: "You should not use Asp.Net MVC if you rely on 3rd party vendor controls for of the UI."

The author doesn't seem to say why (maybe the explanation is too subtle, or I'm too dense). Thoughts? Is it true? Why would this be?

Comment: *This is my personal opinion*: In general, codeproject.com has some weird, untrustworthy content. You should not avoid asp.net mvc because of third party UI controls, that refers to WebForms UI controls which should be irrelevant if you don't know what they are anyway. Today ASP.NET is very competent and powerful technology.

Comment: Oh, I see, he probably was talking about those "dragon drop" controls.

Comment: Yes, those are the ones -_-. With big sites (like this one!) using Asp.NET MVC  I think you have nothing to worry about.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not true. [Such frameworks](http://demos.shieldui.com/mvc/grid-general/basic-usage) are an example how ASP.NET MVC can be used in adjunction with 3rd party controls, also implemented the ASP.NET MVC way (HtmlHelper extensions).